# d3 drag function not being called in version 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm working on building a range slider and I am stuck trying to use the `.drag` function.  Specifically I can't seem to get any function to run during `start` or `drag`.

I have a very simple component here:

```
    <g
      className="handle1"
      transform={`translate(${xScale(value)},0)`}
      onMouseOver={() => onMouseOver()}
    >
      <rect
        className="valueBuble"
        x="-8"
        y="-2.5rem"
        width="1rem"
        height="1rem"
        fill="green"
      ></rect>
      <text
        x="0"
        y="-1.75rem"
        width="1rem"
        height="1rem"
        fill="white"
        textAnchor="middle"
      >
        {value}
      </text>

      <circle r="10px" fill="#fa7070" />
    </g>
```

The entire `<g>` moves according to a value prop.  Now my d3 code with the `drag` function:

```
  d3.select("g.handle1")
  .call(d3.drag().on("start", drag).on("drag", drag));
```

Here I attempted to call a function named `drag` however this function is not being called.  I'm testing this with a `console.log`:

```
 const drag = (event, d) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };
```

I am using React functional components.  Any advice on how to fix the problem.

Code Pen example: https://codepen.io/trevordammon/pen/WNxWQRm

Comment: Can you change your code into a runnable [mre]?

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/trevordammon/pen/WNxWQRm. I attempted to simplify the code as much as possible.